# Runtime Error Cannot read property '_getPortal' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a simple ion-select component in my html file like this:

```
   <ion-row><ion-item class="login-item">
        <ion-label floating> Companies</ion-label>
        <ion-select  [(ngModel)]="storeid">
            <ion-option value="1"> store1</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="2"> store2</ion-option>
        </ion-select> 

    </ion-item></ion-row>
```

And My package.json is like this:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angular2-swing": "^0.7.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.2.1",
    "ionic2-auto-complete": "^1.4.2-release",
    "ionic2-super-tabs": "^2.3.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-swipe-cards": "^1.0.14",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.6",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

When i click to the select in the view it crashes and runtime error stack is as below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_getPortal' of undefined
    at App.present (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:17984:52)
    at Alert.present (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:49299:26)
    at Select.open (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71893:17)
    at Select._click (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:71758:14)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AboutModule/About.ngfactory.js:433:43)
    at handleEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12303:138)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13511:42)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:13099:12)
    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:9278:21)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:9868:38
```

Everything is so simple and I dont understand what can be the problem.

Comment: Do you have something called `_getPortal` in your code?

Comment: no, i havent used anything named "portal" in my source code. 
error comes from main.js _getPortal
in main.js it is used in final compiled code:

 App.prototype.getActiveNav = function () {
        var /** @type {?} */ portal = this._appRoot._getPortal(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__app_constants__["b" /* PORTAL_MODAL */]);
        if (portal.length() > 0) {
            return findTopNav(portal);
        }
        return findTopNav(this._rootNav || null);
    };

Comment: error occurs in this lines in main.js

   App.prototype.present = function (enteringView, opts, appPortal) {
        (void 0) /* assert */;
        var /** @type {?} */ portal = this._appRoot._getPortal(appPortal);
        // Set Nav must be set here in order to dimiss() work synchnously.
        // TODO: move _setNav() to the earlier stages of NavController. _queueTrns()
        enteringView._setNav(portal);

Comment: Show your component (class) code. which is using this select item.

Comment: main.ts is used to bootstrap your app. so check your root component. if you define there any property with name _getPortal and that has undefined meaning it has nothing and you are using this property.

Comment: i realized that it occurs when I use
  "ionic2-auto-complete": "^1.4.2-release", component
in the same view with ion-select
<ion-auto-complete [dataProvider]="service" [template]="withFlags"></ion-auto-complete>

 <ion-select  [(ngModel)]="storeid">
i have not used anything like "getportal" maybe it is used in component ion-auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message in my app. The error was created from custom component module file: `components.module.ts`.

I added this import entry `IonicModule.forRoot(MyCustomComponent)`.

After this, no way to make alert, loading, etc working.

Solution was to remove `.forRoot(MyCustomComponent)`

Hope this will help some guys around